# Select results of query and search those records on original table

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum, where-clause, window-functions

I have the following `table1`:

```
      id       date    desc  amount
12345678 2020-09-11 payment 4999.15
12345678 2020-09-11     tax -548.20
12345678 2020-09-11   total 4450.95
12345678 2020-08-11 payment 4999.15
12345678 2020-08-11     tax -548.20
12345678 2020-08-11   total 4450.95
98765432 2020-09-11 payment   99.15
98765432 2020-09-11     tax  -99.15
98765432 2020-09-11   total    0.00
98765432 2020-08-11 payment  499.00
98765432 2020-08-11     tax -299.00
98765432 2020-08-11   total  200.00
```

I want to select the IDs that earn less than 250 total. I am applying the following query:

```
SELECT id, ROUND(SUM(amount), 2) AS 'TOTAL EARNED'
FROM table1
WHERE desc = 'total' 
GROUP BY id
HAVING ROUND(SUM(amount), 2) < 250
ORDER BY ROUND(SUM(amount), 2);
```

It works well and I get back a table with two columns: one for the ID and one for the total earned. Now, I'd like to get all the data associated to those IDs from `table1`, except the rows where `desc = 'total'`. In this example, the result would be this:

```
      id       date    desc  amount
98765432 2020-09-11 payment   99.15
98765432 2020-09-11     tax  -99.15
98765432 2020-08-11 payment  499.00
98765432 2020-08-11     tax -299.00
```

I have tried subqueries (`SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, ...) AS T;`), but they all look inside the results table and not table1, therefore I don't get the desired output.

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when descr = 'total' then amount else 0 end)
            over(partition by id) total_earned
    from table1 t
) t
where descr <> 'total' and total_earned < 250
```

In the subquery, the window sums the amounts associated to description `'total'` for each `id`. This basically emulates the behavior of your original query, without aggregation. Then, the outer query filters on the total earned and on the description.

Note that `desc` is a language keyword (as in `order by` clauses), hence not a good choice for a column name. I renamed it to `descr` in the query.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. Good catch with `desc`.